# Arrange letters of BREAKAGE such that neither 2 E's nor 2 A's appear together

Tags: combinatorics

> Arrange letters of BREAKAGE such that neither 2 E's nor 2 A's appear together

Gap method doesn't work because AEAE or similar cases are possible. I don't think there is a direct method to do this I tried to break this into $$P(E_1 \cup E_2 ) = P(E_1) + P(E_2) - P(E_1 \cap E_2)$$ but  wasn't able to figure out what events should I chose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $E_1$ be the event that 2E's appear together, and $E_2$ be the event that 2A's appear together. In these two cases we can identify 2E's (or 2A's) to a single E (or A). Then $E_1\cap E_2$ is the event that both of 2E's and 2A's appear together, and you can identify both of 2E's and 2A's to a single E and a single A. $E_2\cup E_2$ is the events that at least one of 2E's and 2A's appear together. Hence $(E_1\cup E_2)^c$, the complement of $E_1\cup E_2$, is the event that neither 2E's nor 2A's appear together, which is what you need.

Then use your formula and you can get the answer.